# How to use two checkpoint files to init the graph

Tags: tensorflow

I've trained two models. Each of them can produce useful representative features. And I want to use the features to train the third model. That means the first two models can produce the inputs to the third model. And I want to use the tf.contrib.learn.train() to train the third model. The question is how should I import the two checkpoint files to the first two models to init the weights. I know there's init_fn and init_op parameters in the function. However, I don't know how to use more than one checkpoint files. Can you help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tf.contrib.framework.init_from_checkpoint.